# Appflow upsert error : ID does not exist in the destination connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, aws-cdk, amazon-appflow

Creating a appflow from S3 bucket to salesforce through CDK with upsert option.

Using existing connection to From S3 to Salesforce -

```
new appflow.CfnConnectorProfile(this, 'Connector',{
  "connectionMode": "Public",
  "connectorProfileName":"connection_name",
  "connectorType":"Salesforce"
})
```

Destination flow Code -

```
new appflow.CfnFlow(this, 'Flow', {
destinationFlowConfigList: [
    {
      "connectorProfileName": "connection_name",
      "connectorType": "Salesforce",
      "destinationConnectorProperties": {
        "salesforce": {
          "errorHandlingConfig": {
            "bucketName": "bucket-name",
            "bucketPrefix": "subfolder",
          },
          "idFieldNames": [
            "ID"
          ],
          "object": "object_name",
          "writeOperationType": "UPSERT"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
..... other props ....
}

tasks: [
    {
      "taskType":"Filter",
      "sourceFields": [
        "ID",
        "Some other fields",
        ...
        ],
      "connectorOperator": {
        "salesforce": "PROJECTION"
      }
    },
    {
      "taskType":"Map",
      "sourceFields": [
          "ID"
        ],
      "taskProperties": [
          {
            "key":"SOURCE_DATA_TYPE",
            "value":"Text"
          },
          {
            "key":"DESTINATION_DATA_TYPE",
            "value":"Text"
        }
        ],
      "destinationField": "ID",
      "connectorOperator": {
        "salesforce":"PROJECTION"
      }
    },
   {
   .... some other mapping fields.....
   }
```

But the problem is - `"Invalid request provided: AWS::AppFlow::FlowCreate Flow request failed: [ID does not exist in the destination conne ctor]`

According to the error, how to fix the problem with the existing connector which results in `ID does not exist in the destination connector`

PS: ID is defined in the flow code. But still it is saying ID is not found.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your last connector operator should be:

```
"connectorOperator": {
  "salesforce":"NO_OP"
}
```

instead of:

```
"connectorOperator": {
  "salesforce":"PROJECTION"
}
```

since you are mapping the field ID into itself without any transformations whatsoever.